# postgresql order by open and closing date

Tags: sql, postgresql

my table looks like this:

```
   eventname varchar(255)
   open int unixtimestamp
   close int unixtimestamp
```

i like to sort the table by soonest,
which means if its a coming event (open and close < now())
PostgreSQL should order the table by open, but if its a 
current or past event (close > now()) it should order the table by close

i tried to archive this with following order by clause:

```
   ORDER BY case when close>1423053440 and open>1423053440 then 'open desc' else 'close desc' END
```

which basically don't work, because the planer don't support asc/desc decoration inside a order by case

any hints highly appreciated

best regards

andreas

Answer (score 0):

Use multiple keys:

```
ORDER BY (case when close > 1423053440 and open > 1423053440 then 1 else 2 end),
         (case when close > 1423053440 and open > 1423053440 then open end) desc,
         close asc;
```

The first expression puts the opens first.  The second orders the `open`s descending.  The third orders the rest using `close`.